# Subpage Conditional

Tags: pages, conditional-content

I am looking for a way to write a condition for a subpage...in other words

`if` we're on the subpage "duck" then do something...`if` not do something else.

I found some code I thought would work, but it shows up on all of the pages under a given parent page, not just on its individual page...I'm only trying to target the individual page.

This goes in functions:

```
// Subpage Shortcode
function is_child($page_id_or_slug) {
    global $post;
    if(!is_int($page_id_or_slug)) {
        $page = get_page_by_path($page_id_or_slug);
        $page_id_or_slug = $page->ID;
    }
    if(is_page() && $post->post_parent == $page_id_or_slug ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my `if`:

```
if (is_child("Youth")) {
    echo "duck";
} else {
    echo "something else";
}
```

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I was thinking earlier...I guess somehow I was thinking that `is_page` wouldn't work for my child page, but I was over-thinking...this is my final code:

```
<?php if (is_page("duck")) { 
    echo "do something";
} else { 
    echo "something else";
} ?>
```

I know, I know it's so simple, but it works - guess I was just having a brain fart.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'll take a crack at this. There's a few ways to go about this. Check to see if page is a direct child, check if it is an ancestor.

Something like below might work for you

```
if (283 == $post->post_parent) {
echo 'this post has a parent of 283 so do this';
}else {
    echo "or do something else";
}
```

Comment: Alex, I have more than one child page...which is why the current code doesn't work...is there any way to make your code work for multiple subpages?

Comment: To make sure my understanding is correct. You want to "do something" on all children of a specific Parent Page. Right?

If so then this should work
 `if(is_page() && $ancestor == $pid) {
            "do this";
}else{
 echo "do this instead";
}`

That should fire off if you're on a page and that page is an ancestor of  $pid where it's the page id

Comment: Alex, I have a main page called "People" then I have subpages or child pages called "Oscar", "Billy", and "Tim"...right now my code displays on all three subpages "Oscar", "Billy", and "Tim". I would like it to display on "Billy" only, if that's possible :) sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This code would only run on a page with a post named 'Billy'
'if (is_page('Billy')) { 
echo "do this"; 
}else{ 
echo "do this instead"; }'

Comment: Alex, I don't have a post named "billy", I have a child page named "billy" :-(